# Python: how to dump the values of a dict to a list respecting the original visualization?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I need to dump the values of a `dict` to a `list`. In doing this, I want to preserve the sorting given when the `dict` is visualized.

Example. This is my dict:

`mydict={10: 0,
 20: 0,
 30: 0,
 40: 0,
 50: 1.0,
 60: 0,
 70: 1.0,
 80: 0.825,
 90: 0.916,
 100: 0.102}`

I dump its values to a list like this:

`y = mydict.values()`

But when I visualize such list, this is what I get:

```
In[1]: y
Out[1]: [0.102, 1.0, 0, 0, 0.825, 1.0, 0, 0.916, 0, 0]
```

What can I do to make sure my list stores the values in the exact order shown by the dict? I want to have:

```
In[1]: y
Out[1]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 0.825, 0.916, 0.102]
```

**EDIT**

If I use an `OrderedDict` while building my dict, the problem remains. My dict in this case would simply be visualized like this:

```
In[2]: mydict
Out[2]: OrderedDict([(100, 0.102), (70, 1.0), (40, 0), (10, 0), (80, 0.825), (50, 1.0), (20, 0), (90, 0.916), (60, 0), (30, 0)]
```

And `y` would still be the same as before:

```
In[3]: y
Out[3]: [0.102, 1.0, 0, 0, 0.825, 1.0, 0, 0.916, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Use OrderedDict from collections module instead of dict.

Comment: No it does not work the way I want. Look at my edit.

Comment: You of course have to add the value to the OrderedDict in the desired order. When writing {10:0, ...} you have already lost the order and putting that into an OrderedDict will not help.

Comment: Yes, of course `y` won't change as you've never reassigned it.